# How to create a method to get resources of a certain type with Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

I have very little knowledge about Jena. How should I create a method to get resources of a specific type?

```
public static String[] getResourcesOfType(String typeName)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * { ?x a <typeURI> }
```

where "a" is the short form of rdf:type.

Or use

```
model.listStatements(null, RDF.type, <ResourceForTheType>)
```

Comment: Can you please explain "model.listStatements(null, RDF.type, <ResourceForTheType>) ".....?

Comment: There is documentation for almost everything in Jena: [model.listStatements(..,..,..)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listStatements(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode))